# How change the font size for Signature Component

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the Signature component in my App. I would like to reduce the font size for buttons CANCEL, RESET of Signature component. Please let me know if any functions available to change the size or style for buttons of Signature component.

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available right now. But it makes sense to have something like that so for the next update (which will be out on Friday June 15th 2018) we'll add the following 3 theme constants:

- `sigButtonOKUIID`
- `sigButtonResetUIID`
- `sigButtonCancelUIID`

So if you want cancel and reset to have a smaller font just create a theme entry matching a small font button (you can derive from `Button`). Lets say you named it `SmallFontButton`. Then in the theme constants you just define the  `sigButtonResetUIID=SmallFontButton` and do the same for the cancel button.

That should provide you with full control over the appearance of these widgets.

Comment: Great Shai. Thank You. I will wait for the update on June 15th.

Comment: @Shai..this update is complete now. can I use it for my App. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, this was deployed on Friday and should work once you update the client libs in Codename One Settings

Comment: Thank You Shai. It works now. But I was expecting it will part of drop down menu items but it did not though it worked when I enter the constants manually.

Comment: I don't understand what drop down menu item you are referring to. Can you provide clarification screenshots possibly in a new question?

Comment: I ahve attached the screenshot. Three values sigButtonOKUIID,
sigButtonResetUIID, sigButtonCancelUIID doesn't show up in this dropdown list. But when I add it manually they started working. Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few options like that. We need to manually add options to this combo box so it doesn't always happen.